# Correct way to build responsive UI on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering what's the correct way to build a responsive UI with flutter. I'm trying to use LayoutBuilder but that seems to only apply to the parent and any component that I have will get a Inifity width.

To give a proper example, I have a screen with the following:

```
class _StartScreenState extends State<StartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          const BaseBackground(),
          LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        MainScreenButton(
                          name: 'Name',
                          image: 'iamge.png',
                          screen: Screen(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          const Footer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I use the contraints.maxWidth here to hide the button or something, it works fine. But, this is the MainScreenButton:

```
class MainScreenButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreenButton({
    super.key,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.screen,
  });

  final String name;
  final String image;
  final Widget screen;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        print(constraints.maxWidth);
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: (constraints.maxWidth < 500)
                ? Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 74, 15)
                : Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 164, 196),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white,
                blurRadius: 0.5,
                spreadRadius: 0.5,
                offset: Offset(2, 3),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return screen;
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network(kImageLocalPrefix + image, height: 100),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      name,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to add the same LayoutBuilder inside the MainScreenButton to (for instance, change the color of the container depending on width), the constraints.maxWidth is always Infinity, so it doesn't really change. I feel like sending the width as parameter to every single component is not the way to go, but I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the problem here, but children inside Rows and Columns by default get infinite max width and height assigned. To solve that you should wrap them in an `Expanded` so they will know how much space they have available. So like

```
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: MainScreenButton(
              name: 'Name',
              image: 'iamge.png',
              screen: Screen(),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

also, as a sidenote, it's pretty pointless to have a Row and Column with only one child. They really are meant to be used with more children.

Comment: Hi @Ivo I've edit my MainScreenButton code to properly examplify the issue. Basically the constraints.maxWidth always returns Infinity so the color of the button never changes. (And in regards to the side note, I have more Widgets in the rows and column, I just removed them to make the code here smaller :] )

Comment: @Icaroto yeah I got the part about the LayoutBuilder inside the MainScreenButton indicating infinite but I still think that it is because the parent Row and Column are giving it infinite space. I still think adding those Expanded widgets might help

Comment: I tried, but Expanded didnt change much :(

Comment: Ok, it was worth a try